# Jest test webpack mock file during run-time

Tags: json, unit-testing, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

Hi i'm using jest to test my react components and i works good and circle ci on github. But I have a test that imports a file named webpack.assets.json that does not exit in circle ci so the tests fail. How do i create a fake mock file to serve as the webpack.assets.json when the test is running in circle ci?

ERROR

```
Cannot find module '../../../webpack-assets.json' from 'loader.js'
```